# jQuery find maximum user scroll value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grab the maximum value when a user scrolls through a page. I have set a timeout so for e.g. when a user keeps scrolling, I need to find till where have they scrolled on the page and store the maximum value

```
var $window = $(window);
var $body = $(document.body);
$window.on('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(jQuery.data(this, "scrollCheck"));
    jQuery.data(this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
        var scrolled_val = $body.scrollTop();
        var max_value = Math.max(scrolled_val,scrolled_val);
        console.log("max value is " + max_value);
        perc = scrolled_val / $body.height() * 100;
        rounded = Math.round(perc / 10) * 10;
        console.log("% value is " + rounded);
    }, 250));
});
```

my code above does not display the max value, but every value the user scrolls to, whereas I need the max value to show. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE** managed to get this working using arrays. Thanks for your input

```
var $window = $(window);
var $body = $(document.body);
var a = []; 
$window.on('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(jQuery.data(this, "scrollCheck"));
    jQuery.data(this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
        var scrolled_val = $body.scrollTop();
        a.push(scrolled_val);
        console.log("value is " + scrolled_val);
        console.log(a);
        var max = Math.max.apply(Math,a);
        console.log("max value is " + max);
        perc = max / $body.height() * 100;
        rounded = Math.round(perc / 10) * 10;
        console.log("% value is " + rounded);
    }, 250));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the object in question is a div with an id of "my_div"

```
var objDiv = getElementById("my_div");
```

objDiv.scrollTop will contain the scroll value from the top down of where the div is currently scrolled, so it will return 5 if we scrolled down 5 pix.    objDiv.scrollLeft will contain the scroll value from the left on a horizontal scroll.    You could store this value in a variable, and then reset the scrollHeight property later.

```
var scrollValue = objDiv.scrollTop;
```

and then later

```
objDiv.scrollHeight = scrollValue;
```

Comment: its just the entire website, so maybe $(document.body)? I'm a bit new to jQuery especially with scrolling and positions. If i swap out $(document) with $(document.body) would that do the trick?

Comment: in jQuery, use $(document).scrollTop() to return the current scroll position of the page.   You can refer back to $(document).scrollHeight and reset it to the value you stored.